# Is it possible to calculate a cumulative sum or moving average with a TimescaleDB continuous aggregate?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

Consider a table with 2 columns:

```sql
create table foo
(
    ts             timestamp,
    precipitation  numeric,
    primary key (ts)
);
```

with the following data:

| ts | precipitation |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-06-01 12:00:00 | 1 |
| 2021-06-01 13:00:00 | 0 |
| 2021-06-01 14:00:00 | 2 |
| 2021-06-01 15:00:00 | 3 |

I would like to use a [TimescaleDB continuous aggregate](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/continuous-aggregates/) to calculate a three hour cumulative sum of this data that is calculated once per hour.  Using the example data above, my continuous aggregate would contain

| ts | cum_precipitation |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-06-01 12:00:00 | 1 |
| 2021-06-01 13:00:00 | 1 |
| 2021-06-01 14:00:00 | 3 |
| 2021-06-01 15:00:00 | 5 |

I can't see a way to do this with the supported syntax for continuous aggregrates.  Am I missing something?  Essentially, I would like the time bucket to be the preceding x hours, but the calculation to occur hourly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question!

You can do this by calculating a normal continuous aggregate and then doing a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) over it. So, calculate a `sum()` for each hour and then do `sum()` as a window function would work.

When you get into more complex aggregates like average or standard deviation or percentile approximation or the like, I'd recommend switching over to some of the [two-step aggregates](https://blog.timescale.com/blog/how-postgresql-aggregation-works-and-how-it-inspired-our-hyperfunctions-design-2/) we introduced in the TimescaleDB Toolkit. Specifically, I'd look into the [statistical aggregates](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hyperfunctions/stats_aggs/) we recently introduced. They can also do this cumulative sum type thing. (They will only work with DOUBLE PRECISION or things that can be cast to that-ie `FLOAT`, I'd highly recommend you don't use `NUMERIC` and instead switch to doubles or floats, doesn't seem like you really need infinite precision calculations here).

You can take a look with some queries I wrote up in [this presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1UoWQQR9VuxXdEI4tmYgUV4TwpgSqU0wEpdofkTMtaGE/edit?usp=sharing) but it might look something like:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW response_times_five_min
WITH (timescaledb.continuous)
AS SELECT api_id,
    time_bucket('1 hour'::interval, ts) as bucket,
    stats_agg(response_time)
FROM response_times
GROUP BY 1, 2;

SELECT bucket, 
    average(rolling(stats_agg) OVER last3), 
    sum(rolling(stats_agg) OVER last3)
FROM response_times_five_min
WHERE api_id = 32
WINDOW last3 as 
(ORDER BY bucket RANGE '3 hours' PRECEDING);
```

Comment: Thanks, the example is helpful, and the presentation also.  Minor typo `last30` -> `last3`.  To clarify, there is currently no way to actually materialize the rolling average or sum with a continuous aggregate, correct?  Seems there could be a performance gain that would become more noticeable as the window gets bigger.

Comment: And yes, no way to do a rolling aggregate in the continuous aggregate, as that messes with invalidation considerably.